# When do qubits get entangled?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

I was just curious; when do the qubits get entangled? Do the qubits get entangled right after initialization or do they get entangled when we apply Hadamard Gates to the qubits?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65007/58382, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17913/58382, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54975/58382, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1631/55

Comment: Just note that Hadamard gate does not prepare a entanglement. You need at least two-qubit gate. For example, apply Hadamard on first qubit and then CNOT on the first and second one. You will get so-called Bell state, where two quits are entangled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Martin Vesely

Comment: Thank you @glS for the related articles, will surely check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, qubits are only entangled by means of 2-qubit gates and not by 1-qubit gates, which only cause a rotation of the qubit state in question. Therefore, 2-qubit gates are needed to provide anything meaningful on a quantum computer other than pure random number generation. Practically, 2-qubit gates (typically a CX - gate) are harder to realize than 1-qubit gates, which also leads to a significantly larger quantum error.